# Don't execute a $resource request in angular when there is already a request running

Tags: angularjs, ajax, rest, request, setinterval

I use a interval of 10 seconds for sending a request to get the most recent data:

```
var pollInterval = 10000;
var poll;

poll= $interval(function()
{
    getNewestData();//$resource factory to get server data
}, pollInterval );
```

This works fine voor 99% of the time, but if the internet speed is really slow(I have actually experienced this), It will send the next request before the current is finished. Is there a way to just skip the current interval request if the previous one is still busy? Obsiously I could just use booleans to keep the state of the request, but I wonder if there is a better(native to angular) way of doing this?

Comment: for started use timeout over interval due to exactly this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making the request, then waiting for that to complete and then wait 10 seconds before making the same request again? Something along this line:

```
            var pollInterval = 10000;

            var getNewestData = function () {
                // returns data in promise using $http, $resource or some other way
            };

            var getNewestDataContinuously = function () {
                getNewestData().then(function (data) {
                    // do something with the data

                    $timeout(function () {
                        getNewestDataContinuously();
                    }, pollInterval);
                });
            };
```

`getNewestData` is the function that actually makes the request and returns the data in a promise.

And once data is fetched, a `$timeout` is started with timer as 10 seconds which then repeats the process.

Comment: This seems to be the best suggestion for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$resolved` property of the Resource object to check if the previous operation is done.

From the Docs:

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
> - `$resolved`: true after first server interaction is completed (either with success or rejection), false before that. Knowing if the Resource has been resolved is useful in data-binding.
> - `$cancelRequest`: If there is a cancellable, pending request related to the instance or collection, calling this method will abort the request.

-- [AngularJS ngResource $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).